# Помогите пишу расширение для chrome не могу заполнить input

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Уважаемые программисты прошу Вашей помощи, изучаю JS и решил полезное совместить с изучением.

**Задача:** сделать приложение для chrome при нажатий на иконку заполняет на [сайте](https://obr.nd.ru/course/89e98fd0-61de-520d-c3ae-5368b1ffdaa3/) форму своими данными (пока что не важно откуда будем брать данные)  всего два поля и нажать кнопку войти.

**ПРОБЛЕМА:** Захожу на сайт обновляю вижу как данные заполняются и срабатывает метод click() по кнопке, и сайт отвечает не заполнен логин такое ощущение он не видит введенные данные при помощи ввода js, в ручном вводе конечно всё нормально

## [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал два файла: manifest.json и content.js https://github.com/RidersWeb/authorization_extensionChrome

содержимое content.js

```
    const input = document.querySelectorAll(".mns-sign-in-input--placeholder")
    input[0].value = 'login@mail.ru'
    input[1].value = 'password'
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector('.mns-sign-in-button').click()
    }, 1000) 
}, 1000)
```

содержимое manifest.json

```
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "name": "A_bobrick",
      "version": "1.0",
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://obr.nd.ru/course/89e98fd0-61de-520d-c3ae-5368b1ffdaa3/"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: А сам сайт на чем написан ? Случайно не на чем нибудь реактивном ? Я тут сталкивался с автозаполнением форм на сайте сделанном на react.js исходники которого были не доступны. Проблема в том, что все состояние input такие движки держат во внутреннем состоянии и просто изменение поля ничего не дает. После долгих танцев с бубном получился такой вариант https://pastebin.com/QLQMnHC9  Особое внимание обратите на функции sendChange и sendBlur, первая собственно заполняет поля, вторая фокус переставляет. Но они срабатывают не всегда, поэтому остальной код вызывает их в разной последовательности

Comment: И да, тот код только для react.js и боюсь только определенных версий. Для других движков/версий может понадобится что то совсем другое

Comment: Спасибо за код буду смотреть, Да всего скорее сайт написан на React.

Comment: Mike спасибо огромное за код, функция работает четко!

Answer (score 0):

Такое бывает когда сайт написан на чем нибудь реактивном, например на react.js. Такие движки хранят внутреннее состояние всех input и если не прошла нужная цепочка событий, то не меняют внутреннего состояния. Надо эмулировать события и при этом дополнительно вмешиваться во внутреннее состояние движка. Для react.js современных версий замена состояния input производится так:

```
function sendChange(target, val) {
    // target - элемент input, val - новое значение
    var lastValue = target.value;
    target.value = val;
    var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
    event.simulated = true;
    target._valueTracker && target._valueTracker.setValue(lastValue);
    target.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
  function sendBlur(target) {
    // Перестановка фокуса на указанный элемент
    target.dispatchEvent(new FocusEvent('blur', {'bubbles':true,'cancelable':false}));
  }
```

После изменения данных в input иногда необходимо переставлять фокус, что бы изменения были применены и активировались другие элементы интерфейса, например.

Comment: Mike спасибо, с input разобрался твой код всё четко работает, 
Может знаешь теперь застрял на selector не могу выбрать select страну и потом появляется новое поле регион.

Comment: @Вячеслав сам select удается переключить в нужное состояние ? я с ними не пробовал. Если переключить удается и надо что бы что то еще появилось, то надо blur переставить фокус на этот select и потом на какой нибудь другой элемент

Comment: Вот как получается так же как я и раньше добавлял значение через value без твоей функции 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8JqF.gif